# Duplicating cells with address in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having 10 columns from B to L in excel. I want to check for duplicates within this Range. But I want to know which cell is duplicating with another cell(need a reference of parent one). Please help me to arrive the solution. Here is the code which i tried to solve by getting the "comment with cell address". It is incomplete.

Please suggest best way for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
Sub bomstruct()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim w As Integer
    Range("A3").Select
    f = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Dim Cval As Variant

    For k = 3 To f

        Cells(k, j).Activate
        Cval = Cells(k, j).Value
        Cadd = Cells(k, j).Address

        If Cval = "" Then
        Else
            For j = 2 To 12

                Cells(i, j).Select
                g = f + 3

                For i = 790 To g

                    If i = g Then
                        Cells(i - g + 3, j + 1).Select
                    Else
                        Cells(i, j).Select

                        If ActiveCell.Value = Cval Then
                            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                            ActiveCell.AddComment (Cadd)
                        End If
                    End If

                Next i
                i = i - g + 3
            Next j
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you searching for "all" duplicates cells,or only if they match a single cell?

Comment: "All" duplicating cells. Let it show the all other duplicating cells addresses as a comment Or any other ways to identify. @ashleedawg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code checks for all duplicates and marks (comment and color) the duplicates. It ignores empty cells:

```
Sub callIt()
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Set the range to check
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 11)
    End With
    ' ===== MAYBE NEEDED ==================================
    ' Remove color
    rng.Interior.colorIndex = 0
    ' Remove comment if there is one
    rng.ClearComments
    ' ======================================================
    ' Call the function with the range set
    colorizeAndCommentDuplicates rng
End Sub

' Colorize duplicates (same .value) in a range and add comment showing the addresses
' of all duplicates found. Ignores empty cells.
' Args:
'   rng (Range): Range to check for duplicates
Sub colorizeAndCommentDuplicates(rng As Range)
    Dim rngValuesArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim currentValue As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, dictDuplicates As Object, rngDuplicates As Range

    ' Create dict to store ranges
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictDuplicates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Write range values into array
    rngValuesArray = rng.value

    ' Loop through range array and find duplicates
    For i = LBound(rngValuesArray, 1) To UBound(rngValuesArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(rngValuesArray, 2) To UBound(rngValuesArray, 2)
            currentValue = rngValuesArray(i, j)
            ' Skip empty cells
            If currentValue <> vbNullString Then
                ' Only check for duplicates of value if we not already have
                If Not dict.exists(currentValue) Then
                    dict(currentValue) = True
                    Set rngDuplicates = getDuplicatesRanges(currentValue, rngValuesArray, rng(1))

                    ' Check if duplicates found
                    If Not rngDuplicates Is Nothing Then
                        ' Add ranges of duplicates to dict
                        Set dictDuplicates(currentValue) = rngDuplicates
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' colorize and add comments
    markDuplicates dictDuplicates
End Sub

' Check for duplicates in range values array and return range with duplicates
' if duplicates exist or nothing if there are no duplicates.
' Args:
'   valuetoCheck (Variant): Look for duplicates of value.
'   rngValuesArray (Variant): Array holding values of a range
'     to look for duplicates of value in.
'   rngTopLeft (Range): First (top left) range of range to look
'     for duplicates in.
' Returns:
'   (Range) Nothing if no duplicate found else Range (Areas) of
'   duplicates found.
Function getDuplicatesRanges(ByVal valueToCheck As Variant, _
ByVal valuesArray As Variant, ByVal rngTopLeft As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngTemp As Range
    Dim arrayDuplicates() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim dictDuplicates

    ReDim arrayDuplicates(0)
    For i = LBound(valuesArray, 1) To UBound(valuesArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(valuesArray, 2) To UBound(valuesArray, 2)
            ' Value found
            If valueToCheck = valuesArray(i, j) Then
                If arrayDuplicates(0) <> "" Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrayDuplicates(UBound(arrayDuplicates) + 1)
                End If
                arrayDuplicates(UBound(arrayDuplicates)) = i & "," & j
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Loop through array with indexes of duplicates if any found
    ' and convert to range
    If UBound(arrayDuplicates) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrayDuplicates)
            Set rngTemp = rngTopLeft.Offset( _
                Split(arrayDuplicates(i), ",")(0) - 1, _
                Split(arrayDuplicates(i), ",")(1) - 1)
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = rngTemp
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, rngTemp)
            End If
        Next
        Set getDuplicatesRanges = rng
    End If
End Function

' Colorize and add comment to duplicates
' Args:
'   dict (Object): Scripting dictionary holding values that have
'     duplicates as key and all ranges of the duplictaes as values.
Sub markDuplicates(ByRef dict As Object)
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim rngDict As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim addresses As String

    ' Loop through duplicates
    For Each key In dict.keys
        Set rngDict = dict(key)

        ' Create string with addresses
        For Each rng In rngDict
            If addresses <> vbNullString Then addresses = addresses & vbCrLf
            addresses = addresses & rng.Address
        Next

        ' Colorize and add comment
        For Each rng In rngDict
            rng.Interior.colorIndex = 6
            rng.ClearComments
            rng.AddComment addresses
        Next

        addresses = vbNullString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats Awesome @Hubisan. it helped me. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting the cells that are duplicate with a conditional formatting rule is one method of 'any other ways to identify'.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .range("B:L")
        With .FormatConditions
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF($B:$L, B1)>1"
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    end with
end with
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped But I am looking for identify the cell number references on duplicating Cells. That will help me to identify and modify the data if required:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro that will add a comment to each cell listing the addresses of all the duplicates.

Read the notes in the code.

I use a dictionary to detect the duplicates, and each item in the dictionary is a collection of cell addresses where those duplicates can be found.

As written it is "sorted by rows", but you can easily change the looping to sort by columns if you prefer.

The cell with the comment is excluded from the list of duplicates.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
     Dim d1 As Object, col As Collection
     Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
     Dim i As Long, j As Long
     Dim S As String, sComment As String
     Dim R As Range, C As Range

Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d1.CompareMode = TextCompare

'many ways to set bounds of the region to be processed
With Cells(2, 2).CurrentRegion
    .ClearComments
    v = .Value2 'read values into array for faster processing
End With

'collect the addresses of each value
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
        If Not d1.exists(v(i, j)) Then
            Set col = New Collection

            'offset from array index to cell address depends on starting point of array
            col.Add Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Address
            d1.Add Key:=v(i, j), Item:=col
        Else
            d1(v(i, j)).Add Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Address
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Add the comments
Cells(2, 2).CurrentRegion.ClearComments
For Each v In d1
If d1(v).Count > 1 Then
    sComment = ""
    S = d1(v)(1)
    Set R = Range(S)
        For i = 1 To d1(v).Count
              S = d1(v)(i)
            Set R = Union(R, Range(S))
            sComment = sComment & "," & Range(S).Address
        Next i
        For Each C In R

            'Exclude current cell from list of duplicates
            S = Mid(Replace(sComment, "," & C.Address, ""), 2)
            C.AddComment "Duplicates in" & vbLf & S
        Next C
End If
Next v

End Sub
```